# python regular expression to validate types of strings

Tags: python, regex, validation

I want to do the following with python:

1. Validate if a UTF8 string is an integer.
2. Validate if a UTF8 string is a float.
3. Validate if a UTF8 string is of length(1-255).
4. Validate if a UTF8 string is a valid date.

I'm totally new to python and I believe this should be done with regular expression, except maybe for the last one. Your help is appreciated!

Comment: Possible dublicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2103071/determine-the-type-of-a-value-which-is-represented-as-string-in-python

Comment: Yea, that one so helpful as well. thanks!

Comment: if you have and problem and solve it with a regular expression, now you have two problems!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regex is not a good solution here.

1. Validate if a UTF8 string is an integer:

   ```
   try:
     int(val)
     is_int = True
   except ValueError:
     is_int = False
   ```
2. Validate if a UTF8 string is a float: same as above, but with `float()`.
3. Validate if a UTF8 string is of length(1-255):

   ```
   is_of_appropriate_length = 1 <= len(val) <= 255
   ```
4. Validate if a UTF8 string is a valid date: this is not trivial. If you know the right format, you can use `time.strptime()` like this:

   ```
   # Validate that the date is in the YYYY-MM-DD format.
   import time
   try:
     time.strptime(val, '%Y-%m-%d')
     is_in_valid_format= True
   except ValueError:
     is_in_valid_format = False
   ```

**EDIT:** Another thing to note. Since you specifically mention UTF-8 strings, it would make sense to decode them into Unicode first. This would be done by:

```
my_unicode_string = my_utf8_string.decode('utf8')
```

It is interesting to note that when trying to convert a Unicode string to an integer using `int()`, for example, you are not limited to the "Western Arabic" numerals used in most of the world. `int(u'١٧')` and `int(u'१७')` will correctly decode as 17 even though they are Hindu-Arabic and Devangari numerals respectively.

Answer (score 2):

Why use regex? I'm convinced it would be slower and more cumbersome.

The `int()` and `float()` method or better yet the `isdigit()` method work well here.

```
a = "03523"
a.isdigit()
>>> True

b = "963spam"
b.isdigit()
>>> False
```

For question 3, do you mean "*Validate if a UTF8 string is a NUMBER of length(1-255)*"?

Why not:

```
def validnumber(n):
  try:
    if 255 > int(n) > 1:
      return True
  except ValueError:
      return False
```

Answer (score 1):

1. int() and check for exceptions
2. float() - but what do you mean float?
3. int() and then check using if
4. using datetime formatting