# Python csv file determine data type

Tags: python-2.7, csv

new student here so please excuse my ignorance, I have searched a lot and not found a solution to my problem. I am needing to import a CSV file with mixed data types [ int, float, and string], determine the data type, then do maths on the ints and floats.

The problem is that csv reader converts everything to strings ( or they are already strings?). I can try and convert to float, and if it throws an error message I know it is a string, but how would I tell if it is a float, as my program needs to determine between the two?

I am only allowed to import CSV and no others. This is my second first-year python subject, and really not sure how to do this.

Edit, found one answer that seems similar to my problem, but it still returns the wrong answers, ints are usually, but not always, still returned as string type:

```
 import csv


 tests = [
    # (Type, Test)
    (int, int),
    (float, float),

   ]

  def getType(value):
     for typ, test in tests:
     try:
         test(value)
         return typ
     except ValueError:
         print 'value error'
         continue
 # No match
 return str

    file = open('adult.csv')
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    filename = 'output.xml'
     text = open(filename, 'w')
    text.write('<?xml version="1.0"?>')
     text.write('<!DOCTYPE summary [')

     headers = reader.next()
     for i in headers:
     print '<name>'
     print i
     print '</name>'
     print '<dataType>' 
for a in i[1]:
    print getType[a]


#for row in fields:
  #  text = row[2]
  #  print type(text)
print '</dataType>'
#for value in i:
   # print type(value)




print '<!ELEMENT summary\n\n>'
#text.write('<element>')
```

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/32397436/1424087

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine data type and perform maths on int and float columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29115619/determine-data-type-and-perform-maths-on-int-and-float-columns)

Answer (score -1):

Ok sorry everybody, think i found some code i think will work:

[determine the type of a value which is represented as string in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2103071/determine-the-type-of-a-value-which-is-represented-as-string-in-python)

SHOULD have searched harder, although still not reliably giving the correct type